# Evitar cambio de tab con javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy trabajando con tabs sobre mi proyecto, 
el tab lo construyo asi:

```
<div class="tab-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" id="unidadrecaudadora"  href="#DatosUR" role="tab">Datos Unidad Recaudadora</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="encargdo" href="#Encargados">Encargados</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="datostransfe"  href="#DatosTrans" role="tab">Datos Transferencia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="aporte" href="#AportParr" role="tab">Aporte Parroquial</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id="DatosUR" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosUR')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Encargados" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.Encargados')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="DatosTrans" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosTransf')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="AportParr" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.AportParr')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y la manera en la que estoy validando el cambio es con js de momento es asi:

```
   $('#encargdo').click(function (event) {
    if($('#btnactualizar').attr('disabled') != 'disabled'){
        var mensaje = confirm('los cambios no se han guardado, ¿Desea Continuar?');
        if (!mensaje) {

        }
    }
})
```

lo que estoy haciendo es que en la pantalla de unidad recaudadora al momento de editar se habilita el boton actualizar, que es lo que se valida en js al momento de realizar cambio de tab si es cancelar devuelve false y no se debe realizar el cambio de tab si no mantener en el actual,

mi problema es que no se como hacerlo no soy experto en js y usando preventdefault() no me esta funcionando o no lo estoy aplicando bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la siquiente manera:

```js
//$('#encargdo').click(function() { //esta linea en vez de la siguiente si quieres que solo se confirme al querer acceder a la tab de encargado.
$('.tab-container .nav-tabs a').click(function() {
  var mensaje = confirm('los cambios no se han guardado, ¿Desea Continuar?');
  if (mensaje) {
     $(this).tab('show')
  } else {
     return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" id="unidadrecaudadora"  href="#DatosUR" role="tab">Datos Unidad Recaudadora</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="encargdo" href="#Encargados">Encargados</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="datostransfe"  href="#DatosTrans" role="tab">Datos Transferencia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="aporte" href="#AportParr" role="tab">Aporte Parroquial</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id="DatosUR" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosUR')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Encargados" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.Encargados')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="DatosTrans" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosTransf')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="AportParr" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.AportParr')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono para lograr el objetivo, es generico por lo que posterior hago las validaciones que necesito!

Answer (score 2):

En lugar de escuchar el evento `click`, debes de escuchar por el evento de bootstrap `show.bs.tab` asi:

```js
   $('.nav-tabs').on("show.bs.tab", "#encargdo", function (event) {
    if($('#btnactualizar').attr('disabled') != 'disabled'){
        var mensaje = confirm('los cambios no se han guardado, ¿Desea Continuar?');
        if (!mensaje) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-fill" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" id="unidadrecaudadora"  href="#DatosUR" role="tab">Datos Unidad Recaudadora</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="encargdo" href="#Encargados">Encargados</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="datostransfe"  href="#DatosTrans" role="tab">Datos Transferencia</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" id="aporte" href="#AportParr" role="tab">Aporte Parroquial</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active fade show" id="DatosUR" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosUR')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="Encargados" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.Encargados')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="DatosTrans" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.DatosTransf')
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="AportParr" role="tabpanel">
        @include('modulos.procesos.unidad_recaudadora.includes.AportParr')
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente propuesta , ya que somo pocos los que aprovechamos los eventos que nos predefine bootstrap.